# Gitlab Ci configure IPV6

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I start with Gitlab CI and i want deploy my code on SFTP server.

I write the .gitlab-ci.yml, after many errors and research, i found a solution.

**.gitlab-ci.yml** :

```
before_script:
  - apk add -U --no-cache lftp
  - apk add git
  - apk add openssh
  
build:
  script:
    - mkdir /root/.ssh
    - chmod 700 /root/.ssh
    - touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 600 /root/.ssh/known_hosts
    - ssh-keyscan -H $HOST >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
    - lftp -d -e "set sftp:auto-confirm yes; mirror -e -R -v --transfer-all ./ /var/www/html/osticket; quit" -u $USER,$PASSWORD $HOST -p 22 
  only:
    - master
```

My Gitlab Runner is Docker on Alpine:latest.

So when i launch a pipeline i have this :

```
$ lftp -d -e "set sftp:auto-confirm yes; mirror -e -R -v --transfer-all ./ /var/www/html/osticket; quit" -u $USER,$PASSWORD $HOST -p 22
---- Resolving host address...
---- IPv6 is not supported or configured
---- 1 address found: XXX.XXX.XXX.XX
---- Connecting to XXX.XXX.XXX.XX (XXX.XXX.XXX.XX) port 22
<--- SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u8
**** Peer closed connection
```

I have looked :

- sshd_config : Port 22 ok on server
- apache2.conf : Timeout 300

I think the problem is IPV6, but how configure IPV6 on my CI ?

Do you have any suggestion ? :)